# Python3.7 function attribute not available from function object before calling it

Tags: function, python-3.7

```
def f():
    f.created_by = "User1"
    pass
```

f.created_by trows AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'created_by'.
i.e.:

```
>>> f.created_by
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'created_by
```

But if I set an attribute externally, is works fine.
i.e.:

```
>>> f.code = "function code"
>>> f.code
'function code'
>>>
```

I just want to know why I am able to a set function attribute without calling it, but not able to retrieve another attribute from the same.

Comment: Well, the code inside the function only runs when you actually call it. I'm not sure what else you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

The code inside the function only runs when you actually call that function.
So you can do this :

```
f()
f.created_by
```

and it will work as you want this bunch of code to work :)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am very new to python and my query might be naive.
How come  f.code = "function code" works and sets the attribute even without calling the function the first time.